# Java: Scanner from File into Arraylist, then min/max/mean/standarddeviation

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader, standard-deviation

The assignment is to create a program that will read from standard input (a file containing a list of integers) into an array, and then finding the mean, max, min, median, and standard deviation of those integers. first things first, here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class DescriptiveStats
{

protected List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public DescriptiveStats()
{
    // default constructor
}


public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{

    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("students.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            scores.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DescriptiveStats stat = new DescriptiveStats();
    System.out.println("Min = " + stat.getMin(scores[]));
    System.out.println("Max = " + stat.getMax(scores[]));
    System.out.println("Median = " + stat.getMedian(scores[]));
    System.out.println("Mean = " + stat.getMean(scores[]));
    int Mean = stat.getMean(scores[]);
    System.out.println("Standard Deviation = " + stat.getStandardDev(scores[], Mean));
}


public int getMin(int []lst)
{
    int min = lst[0];
    for(int i=0;i<lst.length;i++)
    {                                      
        if(min>lst[i])
        min=lst[i];
    }
    return min;
}

public int getMax(int []lst)
{
    int max = lst[0];
    for(int i=0;i<lst.length;i++)
    {
        if(max<lst[i])
        max=lst[i];
    }
    return max;
}

public int getMedian(int [] lst)
{
    Arrays.sort(lst);
    int middle = lst.length/2;
    if(lst.length%2==1)
    {
        return lst[middle];
    }
    return (lst[middle-1] + lst[middle]);
}

public int getMean(int [] lst)
{
    Arrays.sort(lst);
    int mean = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i>lst.length;i++)
    {
        sum = sum + lst[i];
        count++;
    }
    mean = sum/count;
    return mean;
}

public int getStandardDev(int [] lst, int m)
{
    int mean = m;
    int [] array = lst;
    int total = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int result = array[i]-mean;
        int [] all = Math.pow(result, 2);

    }
    total = result/array.length;
    int standev = Math.sqrt(total);
    return standev;
}

}
```

My particular issues come down to this: I don't know if I'm reading in the file correctly. I've followed many instructions from books to website and that seems to be the correct formula for scanner, but the file isn't found. I've tried three different IDE's (BlueJ, Eclipse, Netbeans) to no avail.

Secondly, I've created the methods to take an arraylist as input and called them in a 'public void main(string[] args)' method. I'm pretty sure i can do this, but it won't compile, and i'm not sure what i'm missing.

Finally, I want to make sure that my standard deviation method is correct.
I don't expect any one person to solve all of these, but those are the points at which I'm stuck, and any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If the file is not in the working directory, you need to provide a path to it. Also, main() should be static.

Comment: The main method needs to be static: public static void main(String[] args).

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is to get your program to compile and run (correctly or not). Then you can simply print the values it reads and test whether they are identical to the values in the data file.

To get your program to run, you first need to declare the main() method to be `static`. Also, since you're catching the IOException (good idea, by the way!), you don't need to declare `main` to throw the exception. Finally, since you are trying to read the data inside `main`, you can't access the `scores` field, since it's an instance variable and you don't have an instance of `DescriptiveStats` yet. Besides, since you're passing the array as a parameter to the analysis functions, it doesn't need to be an instance variable. Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader("students.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            scores.add(sc.nextInt());
        }
        sc.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I definitely found this useful and changed my code adjust it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know from where the program tries to read the file, use this:

```
File students = new File("students.txt");
System.out.println("Reading data from :" + students.getAbsolutePath());
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(students));
...
```

Comment: This is actually incredibly helpful. As it turns out, I'll be reading from standard input instead of hard coding the file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have placed the file "students'txt". If it is not in the same location as the class "DescriptiveStats", JVM won't be able to locate the file. So, make sure that the file is in the same path as the class or specify the correct path if you want to take it from somewhere else.

Coming to the second point. You can absolutely call these methods from the main() function. What is the compiler error you are getting?

Appreciate your effort in trying out with different IDEs. But it has nothing got to do with the IDE.

Comment: The compiler error is in regards to the parameters that i'm using for the methods. I figured out that much - I'm using arrays when the variable 'scores' is actually an arraylist. Now, the problem I have is that the file that I'm uploading (which will now be instandard input) actually contains integers (23, 58, 34, 75, etc). Can I declare an Arraylist of type double that will allow scanner to add to it?

Comment: Well....i guess there should be a method in the "List" Class which provides you the functionality to import an array...Just check the Javadoc...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I made some changes in accordance to what people were suggesting. I did away with the hard coded file, and replaced it with standard input. Now, my real focus is:
-Making sure that I'm using array-lists in conjunction with the methods correctly,
-Making sure that I'm correctly able to apply those to standard deviation
Here is my new code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Read from a standard input a series of exam scores,    
 * then compute the min, max, avg, med, & stand deviation.
 */
public class DescriptiveStats
{

public DescriptiveStats()
{
    // default constructor
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(input.hasNextInt())
        {
            scores.add(input.nextInt());
        }
        input.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DescriptiveStats stat = new DescriptiveStats();
    System.out.println("Min = " + stat.getMin(scores));
    System.out.println("Max = " + stat.getMax(scores));
    System.out.println("Median = " + stat.getMedian(scores));
    System.out.println("Mean = " + stat.getMean(scores));
    int Mean = stat.getMean(scores);
    //System.out.println("Standard Deviation = " + stat.getStandardDev(scores, Mean));
}


public int getMin(ArrayList<Integer> lst)
{
    int min = 0;
    int d = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {                         
        d = lst.get(i);
        if(min>d)
        {
            min=d;
        }
    }
    return min;
}

public int getMax(ArrayList<Integer> lst)
{
    int max = lst.get(0);
    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
        if(max<lst.get(i))
        max=lst.get(i);
    }
    return max;
}

public int getMedian(ArrayList<Integer> lst)
{
    Collections.sort(lst);
    int middle = lst.size()/2;
    if(lst.size()%2==1)
    {
        return lst.get(middle);
    }
    return (lst.get(middle-1) + lst.get(middle));
}


public int getMean(ArrayList<Integer> lst)
{
    Collections.sort(lst);
    int mean = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i>lst.size();i++)
    {
        sum = sum + lst.get(i);
        count++;
    }
    mean = sum/count;
    return mean;
}
/**
public int getStandardDev(ArrayList lst, int m)
{
    int mean = m;
    int [] array = lst;
    int total = 0;
    for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        int result = array[i]-mean;
        int [] all = Math.pow(result, 2);

    }
    total = result/array.length;
    int standev = Math.sqrt(total);
    return standev;
}**/

}
```

As you can see, the standard deviation method and its reference in the main method are made into comments. I haven't tried to convert those to array lists yet, since I'm not sure I did the right thing to the others.

Finally, When I run what I have, the compiler doesn't return any errors. Instead, It just hangs, probably having crashed. I'm not sure why. When I use the 'void main(String[] args' option in BlueJ, I submit the name of the text file(Which is in the project directory. theres even one in the main directory just in case that's what's being referenced.

Thank you all.

Comment: good to see you getting the solution..but make sure that you know the exact path from where the file is being loaded...print the file's path using the method file.getAbsolutePath() so that you'll know from where the file is being loaded from, or you'll end up having confusions in the future...